# How to obtain signed digest of HTTPS server response?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am somewhat at a loss here. I would like to make a GET request to an HTTPS server and in addition to the `Response` object I would like to obtain the SSL certificate, and more importantly, the server-signed message digest. Any idea how to achieve this with (preferably) Python?

Comment: That info is not available on the standard response object. I'm not sure it is even available at the urllib3 level. Why do you need this?

Comment: For archiving purposes, where the integrity of content must be verifiable by a third party.

Comment: You can access the [peer certificate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert) on the SSL socket wrapper, that's the best I think that can be done.

Comment: Well, getting the certificate is not the problem, there are about a dozen methods for getting it :-) I need the signed digest.

Comment: Still digging, but can you point out [what part of the SSL exchange](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/HTTP_SSL.html) you are looking to record? Since most of this is delegated to the underlying SSL library (usually OpenSSL) I'm somewhat skeptical this is at all exposed to the Python level.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was on a business trip. If I understand things correctly, I'm looking for the HMAC, so that using the public SSL key I can later on verify that the message still matches the hash, and that the signed hash has not been modified.

Comment: I've poked through all SSl-related objects, including the PyOpenSSL context and session objects, and that information does not appear to be exposed. This is not `requests` or `urllib3` specific; this is just not information that the SSL socket layer provides access to.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, seems to be a pitty and oversight :-( However, I have a suspicion as to why this cannot be exposed in a meaningful way: The message is transferred in chunks, and each chunk is individually protected by an HMAC. There simply **is** no HMAC for the entire message.